# Swift SceneKit - I am trying to figure out if a Node object goes off the screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, scenekit

Using **SceneKit**

I want to make the gray transparent box to disappear and only show the colored boxes when the user zooms in.
So I want to detect when that box's edges are starting to fall off the screen as I zoom, so I can hide the gray box accordingly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First thoughts, but there may be better solutions:

1. You could do an unprojectPoint on the node and check against screen coordinates, do the +/- math on object size and skip Z.  I "think" that would work
2. You can do some physics based collision detection against an invisible box or plane geometries that acts as your screen edges, has some complexity if your view is changing, but testing would be easy - just leave visible until you get what you want, then isVisible=false
3. isNode(insideFrustomof: ) - returns boolean on whether it "might" be visible.  I'm assuming "might" means obscured by other geometry which in your case, shouldn't matter (edit) on second thought, that doesn't solve your problem but I'll leave it in here for reference.